# Looking for a javascript solution equivalent to below jQuery solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several buttons on the page and dynamically I am trying to change the color (background)

I have written a jQuery it's working on all browsers and changing background color based on the CSS param passed to the function.

I am looking for a javascript way of changing the button color that should be working on all browsers similar to the below jQuery implementation.

```
function apply_Color(iframe,CSSParams){

var buttonColor = CSSParams.buttonColor;
var buttonHoverBackgroundColor = CSSParams.buttonHoverBackgroundColor;

jQuery(iframe).contents().find('.search-button').css({
'background': buttonColor,
'background-image': '-moz-linear-gradient(top,' + buttonColor + ' 0%,' + buttonColor + ' 100%)', /* FF3.6+*/
'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, ' + buttonColor + '), color-stop(100%, ' + buttonColor + '))', /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)', /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
'background-image': '-o-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)', /* Opera 11.10+ */
'background-image': '-ms-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)', /* IE10+ */
'background-image': 'linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)'/* W3C */
 });

jQuery(iframe).contents().find('.p-search-button').hover(function() {
 jQuery(this).css
 ({
 'background': buttonHoverBackgroundColor ,
 'background-image': '-moz-linear-gradient(top,' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 0%,' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 100%)', /* FF3.6+*/
 'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + '), color-stop(100%, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + '))', /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 100%)', /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 'background-image': '-o-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 100%)', /* Opera 11.10+ */
 'background-image': '-ms-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 100%)', /* IE10+ */
 'background-image': 'linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 100%)'/* W3C */
 });
});
}
```

I have tried javascript way, no luck; please help.  Please leave a comment if my question isn't clear. I will edit.  I am looking for the syntax that can take linear-gradients for button (background color).

```
obj.style.backgroundColor["-webkit-linear-gradient"] = "blue";
obj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Why would you remove jQuery ?

Comment: @Jerska The requirement of a site, doesn't have jQuery.  Project need is not to have jQuery :(

Comment: Is it possible to add the CSS directly to the iframe as it is generated rather than trying to dynamically apply it with JavaScript?

Comment: @Jerska jquery is quite a heavy library which does a ton of unnecessary things, related to the project, in order to maintain cross-browser applicability, and is explicitly unneeded in most projects.

Comment: @MT0 yes it is! Just have to append a link tag to the iframe's head element

Comment: @MT0 iframe will be implemented on several sites and looking for applying color on the fly based on parameters chosen by the sites.  Constraint here, cannot create css and pass to the frame for all the sites.  +1 for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on MT0's idea, you can just add a stylesheet to the iframe?

```
function applyCss(iframe,stylesheet_url){
    var link = document.createElement("link") 
    link.href = "style.css"; 
    link.rel = "stylesheet"; 
    link.type = "text/css"; 
    iframe.document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
}
```

[EDIT] For linear gradient, you should use background-image not background-color and set the value to the css function

```
obj.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,blue,blue)";
```

Whole script :

```
function apply_Color(iframe,CSSParams){

    var buttonColor = CSSParams.buttonColor;
    var buttonHoverBackgroundColor = CSSParams.buttonHoverBackgroundColor;

    var els = iframe.document.getElementsByClassName('.search-button');

    for(var i = 0; i<els.length; i++){
        els[i].style.background = buttonColor;
        els[i].style.backgroundImage = '-moz-linear-gradient(top,' + buttonColor + ' 0%,' + buttonColor + ' 100%)';
        els[i].style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, ' + buttonColor + '), color-stop(100%, ' + buttonColor + '))';
        els[i].style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)';
        els[i].style.backgroundImage = '-o-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)';
        els[i].style.backgroundImage = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)';
        els[i].style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(top, ' + buttonColor + ' 0%, ' + buttonColor + ' 100%)';
    }
    // same goes for hover
}
```

Comment: I have done this, but this idea is not accepted in the project; looking for applying all browser gradients like the jQuery using the javascript syntax.

Comment: See edit. backgroundImage instead of backgroundColor? obj.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,blue,blue)";

Answer (score 1):

Just on a hunch, I tried the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/FzU3V/2/

(specifically..)

```
target.style.background = "red";
target.style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(top, blue, red)";
target.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, green, red)";
target.style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(top, black, red)";
```

Try each browser - they all show the appropriate gradient. My assumption is that, much like stylesheets, invalid values are ignored. I blew up my IE installation on accident, but this does work on chrome, opera (though it defaults to the webkit version in opera 18), and FF. If this doesn't work on IE after I fix my install, I'll gladly remove this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax is off:

```
obj.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8k5R/)

Comment: Both syntax will work. obj.style['background-color'] = obj.style.backgroundColor. I did not -1

Comment: yes, but obj.style.backgroundColor["-webkit-linear-gradient"] doesn't work

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work in FF. Needs to be backgroundColor.

Comment: Fiddle didn't work in Firefox but it worked in IE.  how can I apply ex:- -moz-linear-gradient(top,' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 0%,' + buttonHoverBackgroundColor + ' 100%)', /* FF3.6+*/ or webkit etc.,